# Rails method on ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a dilema. There's a huge function in my controller to standardise loads of different types of data into one list for the view. So I have this kind of way of handling it at the moment:

```
customer.notes.each do |note|
    to_push = {
      id: note.id,
      title: 'Contact Note',
      type: 'note',
      description: note.notes,
      user: note.user,
      date: note.date,
      action: nil,
      extras: note.customer_interests,
      closed: false,
      colour: '#9b59b6'
    }

    history.push to_push
  end
```

I want to move that out of the controller into the model but I'm not too sure how. I ideally want a method like `customer.notes.format_for_timeline` but I can't figure out how to iterate over results like that in a self method within the class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how. Using a `self` method then `all`:

```
def self.format
  all.each do |item|
    # Manipulate items here
  end
end
```

However, I ended up having a method like this:

```
def format
  {
    id: id,
    note: 'Contact Note',
    # Etc
  }
end
```

Then just used:

`customer.notes.map {|i| i.format }`